# Exiting back to normal mode in terminal buffer from Vimscript

Tags: vimscript, neovim, functions, escape, argument-list

`<C-\><C-n>` is working as (I'd) exepected, but not from a Vimscript.

I am trying to make a script that will:

- open Neovim's `:terminal`
- run a python script
- exit from the terminal input mode
- manipulate the terminal buffer just as text

I already do that manually everyday. That's why the script would help. (:

But I can't find a way to give the `<C-\><C-n>` to the terminal buffer.

Here is the most 'consistent piece' achieved so far:

```
function! AFunction(...)

let firstArg=a:0
let secondArg=a:1
let thirdArg=a:2
let fourthArg=a:3
let fifthArg=a:4

command! -nargs=* AFunctionCommand call Fetching(<f-args>) 
execute ":terminal python a-python-script.py" a:1 a:2 a:3 a:4

endfunction
```

It does work, but I can't find a way to pass the exit key.
The first idea was to concatenate the strings, as [mentioned here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html). Perhaps something that would allow to stablish where is the `<cr>` (after the arguments):

```
execute ":terminal python a-python-script.py" a:1 a:2 a:3 a:4 "\<cr>" . '<C-\><C-n>'
```

If try to do something like:

```
execute ":terminal python a-python-script.py" a:1 a:2 a:3 a:4
<C-\><C-n>
```

It doesn't work since terminal has 'nomodifiable' by the default. The same if trying to call a function with the escape keys.

Yes, it is a horrible Vimscript art, and any comment on the code would be really appreciated, but since this is not Code Review, I would be happy with just the reason why  doesn't work, or where is my logic not working. (:

Comment: CTRL-\ CTRL-N is a normal mode command, so you would need `:exe "norm! \<C-\>\<C-N>"` and yes, you need to make sure to use double quotation marks

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Christian-Brabandt, I didn't realized that the <C* should be escaped. But the problem is that after `:exe ":term..." a:*..` it looks like the 'terminal' process was never done, and nothing below that will be parsed... I commented out the `execute` line and tested with these two in instead: `execute ":terminal "` and `exe "norm! \<C-\>\<C-N>"`.  Thanks again, it's getting close. (:

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something that you want to run under `'makeprg'`?

Comment: Nope, not sure about anything on this. Is there some information that could be added/rephrased to the question?

Comment: Unfortunately `:normal` cannot be used while in terminal-mode (AKA "insert-mode in a terminal buffer"). Use `feedkeys("\<C-\><C-N>")` instead (and no the 2nd "\" is _not_ escaped... yay vimscript)

Comment: Thanks @JustinM.Keyes for the heads up, just read the doc and it does look like the missing chain here, but appearantly I'm failing to escape the double quotes inside the `execute "`'s quotes. Just `feedkeys("\<C-\><C-N>")` gets a "not an editor command". Maybe my question is wrong, I can't pass any command to the terminal buffer, and not only `<C-\><C-n>`. After running the script the buffer says `[process exited 0]`, and the terminal exits after _any_ keypress, except for `<C-\><C-n>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:normal` cannot be used while in terminal-mode (AKA "insert-mode in a terminal buffer"). Instead `feedkeys()` can be used (the second `\` is *not* escaped--yet another Vimscript quirk):

```
:call feedkeys("\<C-\><C-N>")
```

For your specific case, jamming a `feedkeys()` call immediately after the `:execute` doesn't seem to work (could be that "typeahead" is processed before `:terminal` initializes). Instead, use `:stopinsert`:

```
execute ":terminal python a-python-script.py" a:1 a:2 a:3 a:4
stopinsert
```

Note that the `TermOpen` autocmd is also available for terminal initialization.